# Is there a way to get the status of the Twitter API?

Tags: facebook, api, twitter

I make an app that connects to Facebook and Twitter and from time to time I get emails from people about this functionality being broken. I've taken steps to mitigate the problem however I would also like to add a feature which tells the user if the networks are down so they know it's just a temporary issue. Facebook has a JSON page that I can read to find out the current status in my app.

http://www.facebook.com/feeds/api_status.php

However I cannot find a Twitter equivalent. Does such a thing exist?

As a side question is the Facebook one documented anywhere? I'd like to know what to expect it returning when things are not so good.

Answer (score 0):

They don't have a status API. The closest is their status page:

https://dev.twitter.com/overview/status